# remove service from bundle

Tags: java, osgi, equinox

in osgi, i have this setup:
Bundle A has Service S registered. Bundle B processes Bundle A and should remove Service S from it.
can it be done? or is it conceptually nonsense? i didnot find any method for removing the service as i did not registered it (and therefore does not have the serviceRegistration object).

To make it more complicated: Service S actually stems from Bundle B. The goal is to remove S after a restart from B and add a new instance of S.
So i could also implement a S.removeYourself() method... is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the ServiceRegistration object to unregister the service. So you would need some means for Bundle B to inform Bundle A to unregister the service when it is no longer necessary.

Comment: ah.. i didnt see it back than but i just hand the ServiceRegistration to S, so it can deregister itself...